# How to customize ChatMessageListeningEndpoint & ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler for GCM using spring integration?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, spring-integration

Working on customizing ChatMessageListeningEndpoint & ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler but facing issues like

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myNotificationListeningEndpoint' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: outputChannel is required

```
<int:channel id="gcmInboundNotificationChannel"/>
<int:channel id="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"/>
<bean id="toGcmTransformer" class="com.test.cardhash.service.AndroidMessageTransformer"/>

<int:chain input-channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel">
            <bean class="com.test.cardhash.service.MyMessageSendingMessageHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="gcmConnection" />
    </bean>
</int:chain>
<int:transformer id="testTransformer" ref="toGcmTransformer" input-channel="gcmInboundNotificationChannel"
         method="doTransform" output-channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"/>
<int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="gcmOutboundAdapter" channel="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel"
    xmpp-connection="gcmConnection" auto-startup="true"/>

<int:chain input-channel="gcmInboundNotificationChannel">
    <bean class="com.test.cardhash.service.MyNotificationListeningEndpoint">
        <constructor-arg ref="gcmConnection" />
        <property name="outputChannel" ref="gcmOutboundNotificationChannel" />
    </bean>
</int:chain>

<int-xmpp:inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="gcmInboundAdapter"  channel="gcmInboundNotificationChannel" 
    xmpp-connection="gcmConnection" extract-payload="true" auto-startup="true" />
```

Comment: It seems pretty self-explanatory... `outputChannel is required`. Show your configuration.

Comment: We have a JIRA ticket on the matter (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3541), so, looks like we really should take care about that improvement to allow to avoid similar issues. Feel free to vote up for that !

Comment: updated xml, please check whether it is wrongly configured or missed something.